# Making a HTML month day date today week through CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am working on an inhouse analytics reports page and in need of time generated records. My inspiration is how Google Analytics is doing it.

The first thing is having it Hourly, Day, Week, Month and the second thing is to show it in between dates.

I am hoping to show these options in a drop down format. For Hourly, Day, Week and Month, it seems straight forward but to show two date selectors within a drop down seems hard. How can I do that?

Just, as an example, here is how it's shown in Google Analytics.

[image]

This is what I tried:-

```
<?php
    $todo=$_POST['todo'];
    if(isset($todo) and $todo=="submit"){
    $month=$_POST['month'];
    $dt=$_POST['dt'];
    $year=$_POST['year'];
    $date_value="$month/$dt/$year";
    echo "mm/dd/yyyy format :$date_value<br>";
    $date_value="$year-$month-$dt";
    echo "YYYY-mm-dd format :$date_value<br>";
    }

 ?>
    <form method=post name=f1 action=''><input type=hidden name=todo value=submit>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" >
    <tr><td  align=left  >   
    <select name=month value=''>Select Month</option>
    <option value='01'>January</option>
    <option value='02'>February</option>
    <option value='03'>March</option>
    <option value='04'>April</option>
    <option value='05'>May</option>
    <option value='06'>June</option>
    <option value='07'>July</option>
    <option value='08'>August</option>
    <option value='09'>September</option>
    <option value='10'>October</option>
    <option value='11'>November</option>
    <option value='12'>December</option>
    </select>

    </td><td  align=left  >   
    Date<select name=dt >
    <option value='01'>01</option>


    <option value='02'>02</option>
    <option value='03'>03</option>
    <option value='04'>04</option>
    <option value='05'>05</option>
    <option value='06'>06</option>
    <option value='07'>07</option>
    <option value='08'>08</option>
    <option value='09'>09</option>
    <option value='10'>10</option>
    <option value='11'>11</option>
    <option value='12'>12</option>
    <option value='13'>13</option>
    <option value='14'>14</option>
    <option value='15'>15</option>
    <option value='16'>16</option>
    <option value='17'>17</option>
    <option value='18'>18</option>
    <option value='19'>19</option>
    <option value='20'>20</option>
    <option value='21'>21</option>
    <option value='22'>22</option>
    <option value='23'>23</option>
    <option value='24'>24</option>
    <option value='25'>25</option>
    <option value='26'>26</option>
    <option value='27'>27</option>
    <option value='28'>28</option>
    <option value='29'>29</option>
    <option value='30'>30</option>
    <option value='31'>31</option>
    </select>


    </td><td  align=left  >   
    Year(yyyy)<input type=text name=year size=4 value=2005>
    <input type=submit value=Submit>
    </table>


    </form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code you could show us so we know what you've attempted?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar effect by using and customizing the [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker) widget from jQuery UI, together with the [Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) addon, which can be used to pick a time.

[Here's an example](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#multiple-calendars) of how to display multiple months using DatePicker. The Timepicker homepage has [several examples](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-examples) of how to customize it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to have to and from dates within the dropdown as shown in the Google Analytics. Is it possible with this?